# multi select spinner clearAll button android

Tags: android

I'm creating multi select spinner and got problem with Clear All button
http://postimg.org/image/eoyq5jpib/ but "Select all" work pretty good but when clicked on "Clear all" nothing happens. Why I'm getting problem with "Clear All"?

```
protected CharSequence[] _options = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" };
protected boolean[] _selections =  new boolean[ _options.length ];
protected Button _optionsButton;

 public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick( View view ) {
        showDialog( 0 );
    }
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog( int id )
{
    return
            new AlertDialog.Builder( this )
                    .setTitle( "Students" )
                    .setMultiChoiceItems(_options, _selections, new DialogSelectionClickHandler())
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogButtonClickHandler())
                    .setNeutralButton("Select All",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    selectAllStudents();
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Clear All",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    clearAllStudents();
                                }
                            })
                    .create();

}


public class DialogSelectionClickHandler implements DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener
{
    public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int clicked, boolean selected )
    {
        Log.i("ME", _options[clicked] + " selected: " + selected);
    }
}


public class DialogButtonClickHandler implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener
{
    public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int clicked )
    {
        checkAllStudents();
        switch( clicked )
        {
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                printSelectedStudents();
                break;
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL:
                printSelectedStudents();
                break;
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                printSelectedStudents();
                break;
        }
    }
}

protected void clearAllStudents(){
    for (int i = 0; i<_options.length; i++) {
        _selections[i] = false;
    }
}

protected  void selectAllStudents(){
    for (int i = 0; i<_options.length; i++) {
        _selections[i] = true;
    }
}
protected void printSelectedStudents(){
    for( int i = 0; i < _options.length; i++ ){
        Log.i( "ME", _options[ i ] + " selected: " + _selections[i] );
```

Comment: You need to describe what problem you are having with it. What is/isn't it doing opposed to what you expect? Is it crashing? If so, post the stacktrace

Comment: k sorry, when  I clicked on "Clear all" nothing happens.

Comment: ok...do you have it attached to an `OnClickListener` somewhere? Have you set any breakpoints/logs to see what does/doesn't get hit? Help us help you.

Comment: What is `options`? And what is it's length at that point?

Comment: mhm yes. what is strange that is working with Select All button (assignment true) but when i assignment false its didint work

Comment: protected CharSequence[] _options = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" };
 protected boolean[] _selections =  new boolean[ _options.length ];

Comment: also if I change method selectAllStudents(); instead of clearAllStudents();, "ClearAll" button would work